# ImportError: cannot import name 'urlencode' from 'urllib' for pypodio2

Tags: python-3.x, api, podio

Please I have been trying to import the api from pypodio and I keep on getting this error: ImportError: cannot import name 'urlencode' from 'urllib'.I have tried all the suggestions I saw on stack overflow but the error still persists. Using python3. The line of code I am using is:from pypodio2 import api

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this. There python wrapper has not been set up for python 3 (or at least 3.9), the libraries they are referencing are different - instead they need to import urlencode from urllib.parse.  There are a few other areas like that.

Here is an example:

```
class PodioClient():
    client_id = settings.PODIO_SETTINGS.get('client_id')
    client_secret = settings.PODIO_SETTINGS.get('client_secret')
    apps = settings.PODIO_SETTINGS.get('apps')

    def get_client(self, app_name: str):
        for app in self.apps:
            if app.get('name') == app_name:
                return api.OAuthAppClient(
                    client_id=self.client_id,
                    client_secret=self.client_secret,
                    app_id=app.get('id'),
                    app_token=app.get('token')
                )
        raise Exception('No app has been implemented for {}'.format(app_name))

def handle(self, item_id):
    response = PodioClient().get_client('valuations').Item.find(item_id)

# call handle with the item id
```

We really just need the python wrapper to get an update. Any chance you can all get on that?

Comment: Actually, there is a draft PR in for this already. We just need to get it merged soon hopefully?

Answer (score 0):

Download podio library from github and pip install the zip file, then it will show no errors while installing. Also do not directly install from github or pip install Podio2.